# How to stop div's pushing the div under

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a random amount of divs that expand on hover and a div under them that is supposed to stay at the same place when the divs on top of it are hovered. I don't want to use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` because I don't want the hovered divs to go over the div under them.

```js
$('.test').hover(function(){
    $('.test2').toggleClass("up");
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    transition: 0.2s all;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.test:hover {
    height: 60px;
}

.test2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    margin-top: 40px;
    transition: 0.2s all;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.up {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="test2"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with what I've come up so far: http://jsfiddle.net/0beomccn/

My solution stops the div from being pushed down when you hover one div, but if you go from one div to another the div under is getting pushed down for a small amount of time resulting in what looks like a stutter.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: This is happening because you are using css transitions and they are overlapping. Notice how when the transitions are removed, they no longer move the lower div: http://jsfiddle.net/0beomccn/1/

Comment: remixdesign, is there anyway to stop this from happening with using transitions?

Comment: If you're using Javascript to trigger the transition anyway, why don't you set the position of the lower div to absolute in the function for a second, while the transition is taking place.